# Structuremap Singleton Object Reassignment

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, structuremap

I have a singleton object (registered as singleton) that is managed by structuremap.  I then use automapper to map a DTO object to the single objects as follows:

```
_singletonObject = Mapper.Map<SingletonObject, DTOObject>();
```

The automapper instance works fine and assigns the relevant properties within the _singletonObject.  However the assignment seems to disassociate the singleton object in structuremap.

After the assignment above if I use:

```
var singletonObject = ObjectFactory.Getinstance<SingletonObject>();
```

The object is seems to return a new object?  Am I doing something completely wrong?

Comment: Ah me being a noob.  Objects are immutable after structuremap configuration!

Comment: For anyone else who is having a Friday moment you can map as follows: Mapper.Map<SingletonObject, DTOObject>(_singletonObject, _dtoobject);

Comment: You should answer your own question and mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who is having a Friday moment you can map as follows:

```
Mapper.Map<SingletonObject, DTOObject>(_singletonObject, _dtoobject);
```

Note no return value and hence no assignment!